# Can not implement setClickListener() method in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm using RecyclerView and Adapter, I use setClickListener() to click item on View and it will transition to another activity. but Im facing the problem about ItemClickListener interface class.

My Interface class:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
   void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
Context context;

ImageLoader imageThumbLoader;
private ItemClickListener clickListener;
public RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getCarData, Context context){
    super();
    this.getCarData = getCarData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_car_info, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    ...
}
public int getDataAdapter() {
    return getCarData == null ? 0 : getCarData.size();
}   
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter(); // + 1;
}
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView titleName;
    public NetworkImageView imageThumb;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        titleName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
        imageThumb = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
  }
 }
```

My RecyclerView class (CategoryCarActivity) **UPDATED**:

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, ItemClickListener {

RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutScroll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_category_adapter);
    ...
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    new LoadCategoryCars().execute();

    recyclerViewAdapter.setClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivityDemo1.class);

    String car_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Car Id: " + car_id  + ", Price: " + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);
    i.putExtra("price", price);
    Log.i("Car ID: ", car_id);
    Log.i("Price: ", price);
    startActivity(i);
}
// Initialize Toolbar the first time
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_icon_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all tracks under one album
 * */
class LoadCategoryCars extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CategoryCarActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading cars ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * getting tracks json and parsing
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        ...             
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewCategoryAdapter(carsList, CategoryCarActivity.this);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

At line (**UPDATED**):

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, ItemClickListener {
```

compiler happen an error with message (**UPDATED**):

```
Class 'CategoryCarActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View, int)' in 'ItemClickListener'
```

How to fix the problem ? Thank so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity needs to implement the interface!

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener,
        ItemClickListener {

public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    // do your stuff here.
}
```

===============

To fix your latest issue, you must override the abstract method declared in your interface in the activity. To do this, replace:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivityDemo1.class);

    String car_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Car Id: " + car_id  + ", Price: " + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);
    i.putExtra("price", price);
    Log.i("Car ID: ", car_id);
    Log.i("Price: ", price);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

with:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailListCarActivityDemo1.class);

    String car_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
    String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Car Id: " + car_id  + ", Price: " + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    i.putExtra("car_id", car_id);
    i.putExtra("price", price);
    Log.i("Car ID: ", car_id);
    Log.i("Price: ", price);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank @Charlie: I have updated as your recommend, but it apprear new error

Comment: Sorry, I added more parameter: 'int position' in onClick, and it worked ! Thank so much !

Comment: Brilliant :) I edited my answer to include that also.